# Installing Fortran on Windows

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm attempting to install gfortran on windows 10 so that I can start to learn programming in fortran.

I've installed the mingw-w64 files from here:

```
[https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/37287751/][1]
```

Where do I go from here!?

I've also tried using the Msys2 approach described here:

```
[https://masuday.github.io/fortran_tutorial/install_gfortran_windows.html][1]
```

When I run the gfortran command in Msys2 I get a fatal error message saying that there are no input files.

Grateful if anybody has any suggestions, please?

Cheers.

Comment: [This turorial](https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/setting-up-windows-for-fortran-development/1314) could be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] I get a fatal error message saying that there are no input files.

You are getting this error because you didn't provide any files to compile.

Write the program, save it to file and run: `gfortran -o program.exe filename; program.exe`

NOTE: File extension must be `.f90`

Comment: I see, thanks! Is there an IDE e.g. Spyder that I can use to run gfortran then? Cheers.

Comment: You can use [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/)

Comment: +1 to Code::Blocks for Fortran programming. The author has been putting huge effort on the ide to keep it up-to-date with Fortran features and par with big-named commercial ide's.

Comment: Another good option for Fortran is visual studio code.